# Error at XML validation

Tags: xml, validation, w3c

I am new to xml, so if someone could point me out to what is wrong here I would bevery glad.

I am basically trying to validate a xml document in the form

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<tag1>foo</tag1>
<tag2>bar</tag2>
<tree>
    <moreStuffBelow></moreStuffBelow>
    <!-- // -->
</tree>
```

and am getting these error messages from the W3C validator :

```
Errors found while checking this document as XML!
document type does not allow element "tag2" here
document type does not allow element "tree" here
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each XML must have one single root element. In your case there isn't a root element.

[Root Element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element)

Answer (score 1):

All XML needs one and only one [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element):

```
<Something>
   <tag1>1</tag1>
   <tag2>Cipret</tag2>
   <tree>
       <moreStuffBelow></moreStuffBelow>
       <!-- // -->
   </tree>
</Something>
```